# How come decimal to BCD encoder has 10 input lines

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture

Came across to study about decimal to BCD encoder and noticed it has 10 input lines, and four output lines but encoder   should have 2 pow n input lines, so I doubt 10 cannot be in the form of 2 pow n[image]!

Comment: how does decimal differ from BCD?

Comment: do you know what BCD means?

Comment: BCD is Binary Coded decimal I know that, my question is can any encoder hold 10 input lines?  Because 10 is not in the form of 2 pow n? Generally encoder will have 2 pow n input lines and n output line. Is my question is clear? Pls treat me as beginner to this digital electronics :)

Comment: @Silvestor: no generally an encoder will have **at most** \$2^n\$ input lines and \$n\$ output lines. If you have a BC**D**ecimal encoder why do you expect to have more then 10 input lines?

Comment: @curd thanks for the reply,  what my understanding was an encoder can have exactly 2 pow n input lines and not less than that. So when I saw the diagram I m surprised that it has 10 input lines. Is it ok to have total input lines like 7, 9,10,11 which are not in the form of 2 pow n? Will the circuit work properly?

Comment: @Silvestor: having only \$2^n-m\$ input lines instead of \$2^n\$ is the same as having \$2^n\$ but simply not using \$m\$ of them (connecting them to 0). Nobody forces you to use all input lines. So of course, it's always possible to have less than \$2^n\$ input lines.

Comment: I guess calling this exercise a "10 line to 4 line encoder" would have been just too simple, (e.g. 74147, CD40147).

Comment: @Curd, thank you, your reply suffices my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has 10 input lines, because that's what it's for.

You set one - and only one - of the input lines to true, and it sets the four output lines to the specified bit pattern.  So if you set input 7 to true, it outputs 0111, which is binary for 7.

The truth table doesn't say what happens if you set none of the inputs to true, or if you set more than one of them to true.

In theory, you could add a further 6 inputs, numbered 10 to 15.  But they would generate invalid BCD values.  So those inputs are deliberately omitted.